# Does microsoft edge support url schemes/deeplinking in IOS?

Tags: microsoft-edge, deep-linking, url-scheme

URL scheme to open an app from website in MS Edge. Wanted to open "fb://" or "whatsapp://" etc from edge browser. I can open these from safari browser, but not from edge. So, does Edge supports deeplinking?

PS: Opening Edge from apps can be done using the microsoft-edge-http:// or microsoft-edge-https:// URL scheme to open a website in Microsoft Edge on iOS. I want to know the opposite behaviour.

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.appcoda.com/working-url-schemes-ios/),  "fb://" or "whatsapp://" These URLs are known as custom URL schemes created by third-party apps. For iOS 9 and later, the app is not able to open these custom URLs. Apple has made a small change to the handling of URL scheme, specifically for the canOpenURL() method. If the URL scheme is not registered in the whitelist, the method returns false. I also checked the Edge browser document and try to test it on my side, it seems we could only access the system app from Edge browser, not for the third party urls.